# How to make a javascript function to run after another one get finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm using Apache Cordova to develop mobile application. the problem is that I want to get mobile phone number and then send it via jQuery get function for authorization. all functions are OK but the function that get mobile phone number is slower than other and it get finished last.

a summary of my code is this :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    devicePhoneNumber();
    alert("ALERT1"); // ALERT1
};
function devicePhoneNumber() {
    var telephoneNumber = cordova.require("telephonenumber");
    telephoneNumber.get(function (result) {
    alert(result); //ALERT2
    }, function () {
        alert("error");
    });
};
```

I don't know why first a get ALERT1 and after that i get ALERT2.
I want to run my other codes after I get ALERT2.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `telephoneNumber.get()` asynchronous?

Comment: I don't know, that is a plugin :
https://gist.github.com/macdonst/4221765

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `telephone.get` is async, you need to wait for it to finish before you can do your first alert

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

Write your `devicePhoneNumber` function to accept a callback `done`. The callback receives two parameters, `err` (if present) and `result`. Regardless of the `telephoneNumber.get`, the callback will still be called

```
function devicePhoneNumber(done) {
  var telephoneNumber = cordova.require("telephonenumber");
  telephoneNumber.get(function (result) {
    done(null, result);
  }, function () {
    done(Error("There was an error getting the phone number."));
  });
}
```

To use the function now, pass function a callback that accepts the two parameters `err` and `result`. In your callback, check for the error. If it is present, handle it accordingly. You can access the error's message with `err.message`.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  devicePhoneNumber(function(err, result) {
    if (err) return alert(err.message);
    alert("Alert 1");   // alert 1
    alert(result);      // alert 2
  });
}
```

Comment: is there any way to put "result" in a local variable?
something like : 
var PhoneNumber = devicePhoneNumber();

Comment: `result` is a local variable. What do you mean?

Comment: something like : var PhoneNumber = devicePhoneNumber();

Answer (score 1):

add a `callback` function to your `devicePhoneNumber()` function:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    devicePhoneNumber(function(){ //anonymous function for the callback parameter
        /* everything you put in here will be executed only AFTER 
        telephoneNumber.get() has run successfully */
        alert("ALERT1"); // ALERT1
    });

};
function devicePhoneNumber(callback) {
    var telephoneNumber = cordova.require("telephonenumber");
    telephoneNumber.get(function (result) {
    alert(result); //ALERT2
    callback(); //callback function is called here
    }, function () {
        alert("error");
    });
};
```

Comment: @naomik why is it unconventional? you used arguments in your callback-function, i did not - that's the only difference. and for example a lot of `jQuery` callbacks don't use or don't need arguments, so i don't think it's that uncvonventional.

Comment: Your solution is completely inflexible. It forces you to handle all phone numbers the same way because the `alert` is happening within `devicePhoneNumber`. By using the parameters, you invert the control, and the calling function (`onDeviceReady` in this case) can handle the responses as needed.

Comment: The primary difference is your API can only be used one way. My API can be used in any way.

Comment: Both answers are true and helped me, I don'n know which one is the best answer

Comment: @Salman, they both work, yes, but only one gives you [Inversion Of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)

Comment: @naomik my API does exactly what the question was asking for. he did not ask for error handling or something like that. he just wanted to execute function B after function A was done. you just made it unnecessarily complicated and added stuff the question wasn't even asking for. for a good learning process, my answer is the better one for sure. (if he takes your code, he might not even know what he is doing).

Comment: @northkildonan, don't be offended, I'm just thinking one step ahead and made a completely reusable function.

Comment: @northkildonan thank you, but naomik's answer is more detailed. I will use your code in my app for it's simplicity, I don't need Error handling in this project, but I'll go and learn more about using callbacks with Error handling.

Comment: @northkildonan, re: "if he takes your code, he might not even know what he is doing" I explained the design of my solution very thoroughly.

Comment: @naomik doesn't matter if you explained your "design". he doesn't even know what callback functions are. so for the first use of a callback function, my example is better for sure. plus, about "thinking one step ahead" - keep your feet on the ground - you just added arguments to your callback function, that's all.

Comment: @northkildonan lol i think i'm almost flattered how upset you got that i tried to teach you a way to improve the api. He may or may not know what a callback is, but you certainly don't understand the benefits of inversion of control. you'll get the hang of it tho ^.^

Comment: @naomik Hi, I just could'nt resist to comment. Thanks to the argument of @northkildonan and reading the comments I understood at least in some part about `Inversion of control`. I felt the comments at least made me understand how to approach a Async solution. Thanks to both of you guys @northkildonan and @naomik. Without @northkildonan arguments and solution provide by @naomik, It would have been difficult for me to understand why @naomik solution is generic. I would have passed it at just another solution to a specific problem

Comment: @frank I'm glad I could help you out ^.^